# How to make Facebook automatically redirect from a page to another?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

If you access `www.facebook.com/dell` you'll be redirected to the Dell page of your country.

Can I make the same thing with my page?

Like, when you access `www.facebook.com/RedPurpleSecondPage` to be redirected to `www.facebook.com/RedPurple` without having to click anywhere?

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your question is that this is *not possible* due to the Facebook.com domain name belonging to Facebook rather than belonging to you.

If you were the owner of the domain name then you would be able to set a redirect.